# Calling multiple intents at the SAME time in my amazon lex bot using a lambda function (python)

Tags: python, lambda, amazon-lex

Does anyone know how to call multiple intents at the same time in an amazon lex bot using a lambda function (python)

For example:
If i have 2 intents, IntentA and IntentB. It is easy to call the intents separately and get a response, what i’m trying to figure out is if there is a way to call both IntentA and IntentB in 1 interaction (one phrase)

I try doing this by writting phrases that match the utterances but the bot only registers as if i’m calling only IntentA

I tried defining a variable that captured what was written by the user:

user_input == event[‘inputTranscript’]

Then created a function that tries to call both intents

If ‘IntentA’ in user_input and ‘IntentB’ in user_input: ..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the short answer here is that what you're trying to do is not possible. If you attempted multiple parallel calls to Lex for the same user you'd receive a multiple concurrent calls exception.

What exactly are you trying to achieve?